# Allow CORS With Laravel and Angular2

Tags: php, laravel, angular, wamp

I'm creating a Laravel web app that will act as an API for an Angular2 app, for now i'm hosting the Laravel app on WAMP server on windows
laravel is on `localhost:8000` and Angular is on `localhost:4200`
I've created the middleware for CORS like that:

```
class Cors {
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Token-Auth, Authorization');
    }
}
```

When calling my api url I get this:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8000/api/myapi. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access

I'm pretty sure it's not something with the middleware because the api works when I `ng build` the angular app, it just doesn't work with `ng serve` when serving on `localhost:4200`

any ideas?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The preflight request is a `HEAD` request. You should list it in `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`.

Your `handle` will be like so:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $response = $next($request);
    $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', $request->header('Access-Control-Request-Headers'));
    $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    return $response;
}
```

Comment: thx for your reply,,, I don't really get it, shall I make it like `GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD` ? i tried this and still not working

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

It turned out to be something with chrome itself, the app works just fine on edge or any browser,, in order to make it work on chrome,, install this plugin.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi/related?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider using [this](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) package.